# How to get correct time format in pywinrt

Tags: python, windows-runtime

I'm using pywinrt to access the MediaControls.
My goal is to access the various time properties from the GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionTimelineProperties Class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssessiontimelineproperties?view=winrt-19041)

I don't know what kind of format the timestamps are and how to convert them to minutes:seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should return a [TimeSpan struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.TimeSpan?view=winrt-19041), which has a property duration.

```
> x = wwf.TimeSpan()
> x
<_winrt_Windows_Foundation.TimeSpan object at 0x000001EE9A331A50>
> dir(wwf.TimeSpan)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'duration']    
> x.duration
0
```

That's expressed in 100-nanosecond units. So you should be able to convert from that.